# Notifying about task finishing its work

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm thinking of a simple way of reacting on task finishing its work. I came up with the following solution (paste it to WinForms application with a single button to test):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Thread thread;

    public void DoFinishWork() {

        // [4] 
        // UI thread - waiting for thread to finalize its work
        thread.Join();

        // Checking, if it really finished its work
        MessageBox.Show("Thread state: " + thread.IsAlive.ToString());
    }

    public void DoWork() {

        // [2]
        // Working hard
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    public void FinishWork() {

        // [3]
        // Asynchronously notifying form in main thread, that work was done
        Delegate del = new Action(DoFinishWork);
        this.BeginInvoke(del);

        // Finalizing work - this should be switched
        // at some point to main thread
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        // [1]
        // Schedule the task
        ThreadStart start = new ThreadStart(DoWork);
        // Schedule notification about finishing work
        start += FinishWork;

        thread = new Thread(start);
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

This is meant to be a simple cancel scenario, so there will be only one thread, which will be running in parallel to the UI thread.

Is there a simpler (or more thread-safe) way of implementing this kind of notification for the `Thread`?

Please take into consideration two facts:

- The only way i *can* terminate the thread is to `Abort` it (that's because I have no control over what is being done in the thread - 3rd party code)
- Thus, I cannot use `BackgroundWorker`, because it only provides way of *graceful* termination.

Comment: Isn't [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is a good place to raise this question

Comment: I rephrased the question.

Comment: Which .NET Framework are you using? do you explicitly need to use Thread?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a simpler (or more thread-safe) way of implementing this kind of notification for the Thread?

<strike>Yes, use the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and let the framework worry about managing the thread</strike>

```
Task.StartNew(() => {
   // do some stuff
}).ContinueWith((task) => {
   // do some stuff after I have finished doing some other stuff
});
```

Or alternatively, since you are working with WinForms, use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker) and handle the [RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.onrunworkercompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.

I mistook your notion of *kill* for *cancel* - there is no reliable way of actually killing a thread in .NET, even the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx) suggests that using `Abort` is more or less a gamble and gives absolutely no guarentees that the thread will actually be killed. Also, it will leave the thread and, as a consequence, the application in an unpredictable state so if you are willing to take that risk then that's up to you.

One alternative is to simply let the thread play out but just ignore the results, depending on the size of the task it might not be that big a deal.

Comment: How can I kill such task?

Comment: @Spook you don't, once you are done the thread is automatically put back into the thread pool and made available for some other resource (or, if the framework sees fit, it deals with cleaning it up).

Comment: My requirement is that user will be able to kill the task (that's one scenario, second is finishing gracefully with a way to react to this situation). The thread actually runs a non-breakable script interpreter and I have to give user an option to terminate script if it goes into endless loop. That's why I'm using Thread instead of BackgroundWorker.

Comment: @Spook what your talking about isn't *killing* a task, it's *cancelling* a task (2 completely different things) and both the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx) and [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync) support this.

Comment: Please read my whole question including the two notes I included at the bottom. I cannot *cancel* the task, I *have* to *kill* the task, because there is no way of stopping it gracefully.

Comment: @Spook apologies I clearly overlooked those last 2 points. In that case, then no, there isn't really any other way. If you have no control over the thread then your only option is to `Abort` - however, I would definitely not rely on this because the `Abort` method is undocumented so as long as your happy that the thread is going to be in an unpredictable state then go ahead.

Comment: Actually, it seems to be documented: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.abort(v=vs.110).aspx . I cannot let the thread play as I stated in one of my comments: *The thread actually runs a non-breakable script interpreter and I have to give user an option to terminate script if it goes into endless loop.* Thanks for the ideas though.

Comment: @Spook what I meant with "undocumented" was there is no guarantee with what `Abort` is going to do, the main concern is it could end up leaving the app in a corrupt state. It's a difficult one, however, it does sound like `Abort` is really your only option; which for me rings alarm bells.

Answer (score 0):

Although you need `Abort` to kill the thread, you can still use the TPL. You could start that thread within the task, and wait for it as well as for an `CancellationToken`. When the task is cancelled before the thread finishes, you can call `Abort` on the thread.

It would look something like that:

```
// In your class:
ManualResetEvent threadFinished = new ManualResetEvent(false);

// In your calling function (button1_Click):
Task.Run( () => {

    ThreadStart threadStart = new StreadStart(DoWork);
    threadStart += () => { threadFinished.Set(); }
    Thread thread = new Thread(threadStart);
    threadFinished.Reset();

    thread.Start();
    WaitHandle waitCancel = cancellationToken.WaitHandle;
    int waited = WaitHandle.WaitAny( new WaitHandle[]{ waitCancel, threadFinished } );

    if (waited == 0 && cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        thread.Abort();
    else
        thread.Join()

});
```